# Fake IMAP on PHP

Tags: php, imap

I have developed a communication system in PHP. It would be amazing if users can access the system with a mail software through IMAP.
Is there any chance to achieve this goal?

Comment: Yes...? By implementing an IMAP interface for it...?

Comment: Yes, but writing non-blocking multi-IO frameworks in PHP is a complete pain in the rear end and not worth doing, because of its single process, single threaded nature. You will need to choose another language for this part of you system.

Comment: What do you think is the easiest way?

Comment: Assuming that the messages in the communications system are stored in a database, then PHP is absolutely able to handle this. You can use the header() function to override the HTTP headers. You will want to use disconnected IMAP, though. I suppose that DaveRandom means not to try to implement online IMAP in PHP.

Comment: @dotancohen what do you exactly mean by "disconnected imap"? and what's the way to achieve this?

Comment: Disconnected IMAP means that the client makes a connection, checks/downloads (actually syncs) new mail, and then disconnects. It is similar to POP3 in that users read mail from their local machine (cache) and only use IMAP to sync folders.

Comment: @dotancohen Ok, it would be nice. Could you give me some PHP stuff I can work on? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you see my answer below? I link to the Java and Google IMAP API specs. See what methods they implement, and implement them in PHP. I can code it for you if you like, but I'm expensive!

Comment: @dotancohen ahah lol! Are you saying that nothing already exists in PHP?

Comment: Of course not, PHP is not an IMAP server.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "something written in php suitable for my purpose".. is the answer the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMAP is a text-based, open protocol. Just implement [these](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) [methods](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions).

Comment: I don't want to connect to gmail, I want to use a source of data, elaborated by php, through imap... How can I do it?

Comment: You don't have to connect to Gmail. Implement the IMAP methods just like any IMAP server would do. The fact that you are handling communications other than email, so long as they are plaintext and MIME-encoded attachments, is irrelevant. You can't stream audio or video, though, as IMAP does not support that.